# How to add a maxvalue with different on the same axies as before

Tags: r, plot

I draw a boxplot and I want to draw a value at the same axies of boxplot with different color

```
 boxplot(ov, las=1)
 par(new=TURE)
 plot(ma)
```

ov like this

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
A 46.6 33.7 39.4 34.4 37.7 32.0
B 49.6 40.9 42.4 34.4 37.7 49.8
C 55.3 33.8 54.8 34.4 52.2 37.9
D 40.6 35.8 36.3 34.3 40.3 43.8
```

and ma like this

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] 55.3   53 54.8 58.2 58.3 57.3
```

and when I plot(ma) the axies change, I want to hold the boxplot axies and at this boxplot at each columns draw the ma value. but my code draw two different plot and overlap it  how do I get I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the axis limits in both plots to guarantee they are the same:

```
plot(ov,last=1,ylim=c(30,60))
par(new = T)
plot(ma, ylim = c(30,60))
```

Comment: but the xlim not hold the same

Comment: how to insure the boxplot  and plot  has the same  x axies limit

Comment: Oh, I think I understand your problem now. If you use `plot(ma,axes=F)` you will be able to maintain the original boxplot axis.

Comment: but plot(ma,axes=F) only draw a point it didn't draw a series of point  like I think

Comment: how to draw plot  onto a boxplot  draw

Answer (score 0):

I want to draw the maxValue ma to the boxplot, This works well

```
boxplot(vo, las=1, ylim=c(20,60), xlim(0,6))
par(new=TRUE)
boxplot(ma, border="red", axes=F, ylim=c(20,60), xlim(0,6))
```